# PHP - file upload to root folder

Tags: php, file-upload, directory

I have a structure of folders:

```
* htdocs
  * docs
  * admin
    * php
      * upload.php
```

How can I (with move_uploaded_file() function) move uploaded file to docs folder when the script is in php directory? I tried:

```
    $target_file = '../docs/' . basename($_FILES["plik"]["name"]);
```

but I'm getting:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(../docs/file.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, that is gonna work `$target_file = __DIR__ . '/../../docs/' . basename($_FILES["plik"]["name"]);`

I am not sure that your code is secure, because it is possible to upload php file and execute it.